# click an imageview in a listview works if i do it inside my custom adapter but not in main activity

Tags: android

I have a listview which has an image.I want to make an action when the image is clicked.
Doing that from my adapter , works ,but I want to do it from my mainactivity where the listview lies.

I have my custom adapter:

```
ImageView myImage=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.myimage);
            byte []temp = theItems.getImagemyItems();
            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(temp, 0, temp.length);
            myImage.setImageBitmap(image);

            myImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "CLICKED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      


                }
            });
```

The above works fine.
If I try from mainactivity:

```
View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.showadapterlist, null);
this.imageView = (ImageView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.myimage);   

 imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "CLICKED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      

                }

            });
```

It doesn't work.Nothing happens.

Comment: did you remember to use setContentView on the inflated view, or somehow add it to a currently layout that the activity is already showing?

Comment: @android developer:Yes, I used setContentView

Comment: I think you should show the entire getView function . using onClick="" doesn't always fit ones needs, and there are plenty of events other than clicking .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the onTouch event, or change the image for a imagebutton...

But it's better if you do it with the main onClick method()

```
@Override
public void onClick(final View v) {
         switch(v.getId()){
             case R.id.myimage:
                  //Do it when myimage is clicked
                  Toast.makeText(class.this, "CLICKED!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                   
             break;
             case R.id.otherID:
                  //Do something when other item is clicked
             break;
          }

}
```

And say goodbye to the onClick listeners...

Other options is setting the property onclick in the layout... An example:

```
 <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/myimage"
      android:layout_width="170dp"
      android:layout_height="115dp"
      android:onClick="yourmethodname"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"
      android:src="@drawable/iconcamera3" />
```

And in the java class add:

```
public void yourmethodname(final View v) {
     Toast.makeText(class.this, "CLICKED!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
     //Do anything what you want to do on the onClick event

}
```

I don't like to use the onclick listeners, so I use the methods and never has failed.. try it...

EDIT:
For use the first way, overriding the onClick method, first we have to implement onClickListener:

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
public class AnyClass extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
@Override
public void onClick(final View v) {
         switch(v.getId()){
             case R.id.myimage:
                  //Do it when myimage is clicked
                  Toast.makeText(class.this, "CLICKED!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                   
             break;
             case R.id.otherID:
                  //Do something when other item is clicked
             break;
          }

}
}
```

Comment: :thanks !It worked with "onClick="yourmethodname".With onClick listeners it doesn't work!

Answer (score 2):

You dont have to set an OnClickListener to the ListView object. You can pass the click listener to you adapter when creting it. Try something like this:

```
class YourActivity extends Activity {
    protected onCreate(Bundle saveInstaceState) {
       super.onCreate(saveInstaceState);
       // some code here
       YourAdapter adapter = new Adapter(this, clickListener);
       listview.setAdapter(adapter);
       // more code here
   }
}
```

and your class adapter should have a constructor that saves this listener:

```
public YourAdapter {
    public YourAdapter(Context context, OnClickListener listener) {
      // set everithing you need
      this.listener = listener;
    }

    public View getView (...) {
    // do everithig you need
    myImage.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }
}
```

Comment: :thanks for your help.I wanted to do it "my way".Also,I already use OnItemLongClickListener for the adapter and putting also another click listener , I don't know.(upvoted)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this attributes to your imageview:

android:focusable="false"

android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

android:clickable="false"

Comment: :Hello , it doesn't work.(I don't understand why "clickable="false"" since I want to be clickable (i tried it also with "true").

Comment: Sorry. My bad. Misread the question. i thought you wanted to use onItemClickListener